# How do I get past the empty Xcode Organizer window in order to provision a development device?

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm new to iOS development. I just installed Xcode 3.2.4 and the iOS 4.1 SDK on my Intel iMac running Snow Leopard. According to the docs, I first need to create a development profile by specifying a device (which in my case is an iPod touch 4G), but the Organizer window that I open up after starting Xcode comes up fully blank.

Screenshot 1: http://img15.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110305at104.png/

In addition to that, when I click on "Create a new Xcode project for Mac OS X or iPhone OS" on the Xcode welcome screen, I do not have an option to start a new "Cocoa Touch" project.

Screenshot 2: http://img18.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110305at110.png/

Comment: I understand that I'm using an older version of Xcode and the SDK (currently at 3.2.5 and 4.2 respectively), but this is just a point release difference and, as such shouldn't affect anything at such an early stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have the iOS SDK installed, or installed properly. Also, most developers will have upgraded to Xcode 3.2.5 a long time ago, so we won't be able to accurately compare what you're seeing to our own installations. Let me strongly suggest that you download the latest iOS SDK and install that. Once you get the current SDK installed, I think both issues that you're asking about will go away.

Comment: I couldn't have just installed Xcode without the iOS SDK since the installer is "Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg", but I still went ahead and re-installed it, and it bloody worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it -- you're better off with the latest anyway.

Comment: I was thinking of downloading the latest one, but 3.5GB just for a 0.0.1 version upgrade, especially in India, is just not worth it... Thanks!